# Angular template view with utf-8 chars doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, utf-8, hebrew, angularjs-ng-route

I try to use "ngroute" to load html templates.
Everything works fine, but when I try to show words in Hebrew in the "ng-view", I get only question marks instead of the Hebrew chars (???????????).
in the `<head>` tag I added `<meta charset="utf-8">`
and if the Hebrew is static in the page it works fine.
but when I use "ngroute" to load it it doesn't.

```
<head>

<!-- start: Meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<!-- end: Meta -->

<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- end: CSS --></head>
```

Any idea? Is there anything I should add to the html view page?

Comment: Create a plunker or try with this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

Comment: it didn't work. but when i added the <meta meta charset=utf-8> tag to the template and not just to the <header> it fixed the problem

Comment: Probably your template files are saved in a different encoding than UTF-8, probably in Windows-1251 encoding. What you have to do, is to change the  encoding format of the file using an advanced editing tool like notepad++ or sublime2.

Answer (score 3):

I added the `<meta meta charset=utf-8>` tag to the all the templates html and not just to the `<head>` and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved by resaving the html template file with utf-8 encoding. In Visual Studio, `Save As` > `Save with Encoding...` button.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well for Danish characters and symbols.

I was missing the `charset = utf-8` in `/.editorconfig` under the angular project!
So it defaulted to `Windows-1251`.

This worked for all new files and when resaving old ones with wrong encoding.