# Angular 5 set document title with html escaped (entities) characters

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

Seems to be simple, but I can't find the easy solution.
I'm using Title service to put title at document. This is working fine, see the documentation here:
https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

My problem is with the especial characters. In my code the title is set by routing service, but my pages titles have special characters. Take the example: page title "Início", the í character do not format properly.

There's some function or service to do this in Angular?

My code, the problem is in setTitle:

```
AssinarEventosRoute(): any {
        this.router.events
            .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
            .map((route) => {
                while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
                return route;
            })
            .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
            .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
            .subscribe((event) => this.titleService.setTitle(`${event['title']} | Gerencial ISP 2`));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a charset tag in your HTML file:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Also, your .ts files should be encoded in UTF-8 as well.

[Angular-CLI/Angular2: Non-standard chars only load correctly in index.html, not in components via ng serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504558/angular-cli-angular2-non-standard-chars-only-load-correctly-in-index-html-not)

[Angular template view with utf-8 chars doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436890/angular-template-view-with-utf-8-chars-doesnt-work)

Comment: Yes, my .ts was wrong, setting to utf-8 do the trick. Thanks.